# switch cases not opening, getting choice through return on a menu function

Tags: c++

I am having trouble using a switch inside a do-while loop. menu is displaying, but after selection it is just displaying the menu again rather than opening up the proper switch case. and help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried looking for help and could not seem to find much.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//function prototypes
int DisplayMenu(); //shows menu and returns input
double CalcAreaCircle(double radius ); //returns the area of the circle
double CalcAreaRectangle(double length, double width ); //returns the area     of a rectangle
double CalcAreaTriangle(double base, double height ); //returns the area of a triangle

int Choice;
double AreaOfCircle;
double radius;
double AreaOfRectangle;
double length;
double width;
double AreaOfTriangle;
double base;
double height;

//function main
int main()
{

    Choice = -1;
    while (Choice != 4)
    {
        Choice = DisplayMenu();
        switch (Choice)
            {
                case '1':
                    {
                    cout << "What is the radius of the circle?" << endl;
                    cin >> radius;
                    cout << endl;
                    AreaOfCircle = CalcAreaCircle(radius);
                    cout << endl << "The area of your circle is " << AreaOfCircle << endl;
                    break;
                    }
                case '2':
                    {
                    cout << "what is the length of the rectangle?" << endl;
                    cin >> length;
                    cout << endl << "What is the width of the rectangle?" << endl;
                    cin >> width;
                    cout << endl;
                    AreaOfRectangle = CalcAreaRectangle(length, width);
                    cout << endl << "The area of your rectangle is " << AreaOfRectangle << endl;
                    break;
                    }
                case '3':
                    {
                    cout << "What is the base of the triangle?" << endl;
                    cin >> base;
                    cout << endl << "What is the height of the triangle?" << endl;
                    cin >> height;
                    cout << endl;
                    AreaOfTriangle = CalcAreaTriangle(base, height);
                    cout << endl << "The area of your triangle is " << AreaOfTriangle << endl;
                    break;
                    }
            }
    }

system ("pause");
return 0;
}

//function DisplayMenu
int DisplayMenu()
{
int selection;

cout << "What would you like to know the area of?" << endl;
cout << "\t1. Area of a Circle." << endl;
cout << "\t2. Area of a Rectangle." << endl;
cout << "\t3. Area of a Triangle." << endl;
cout << "\t4. Quit." << endl;
cin >> selection;

while (selection < 1 || selection > 4)
{
    cout << "Please enter a valid option." << endl;
    cin >> selection;
    cout << endl;
}

return selection;
}

//function CalcAreaCircle
double CalcAreaCircle(double radius)
{
double area;
const double PI = 3.14159;

area = PI * (area * area);

return area;
}

//function CalcAreaRectangle
double CalcAreaRectangle(double length, double width)
{
double area;
area = length * width;

return area;
}

//function CalcAreaTriangle
double CalcAreaTriangle(double base, double height)
{
double area;
area = base * height;

return area;
}
```

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code with the debugger?

Comment: I'm not a C++ developer, but shouldn't for example `case '1':` be `case 1:`? The apostrophe `'` should only be put around chars I believe.

Comment: program opens with no issues. options 1-3 cause it to just display the menu again. option 4 works as it should and closes the program.

Comment: `case '1':` is the same as saying `case 49:`

Comment: You have no option 4 it seems. But as I said in my comment edit, apostrophes are only used when specifying a character. I.e. `'A'` or `'f'`, etc. Numbers should just be `1`, `2`, `3` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DisplayMenu()` returns `int`. But your `case` statements are using `char` literals. When comparing `char` to `int`, it uses the character's code, e.g. `case '1':` is equivalent `case 49:`. Change your cases to use integer literals.

```
case 1:
```

and so on.

Comment: thank you. this solved my problem. whole program works as it should now. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @Myles : You should mark this as the accepted answer if it solved your problem. This can be done by pressing the check mark on the left of the answer. Doing so will mark the question as solved and will reward the answerer (in this case Barmar) with 15 reputation points, and the asker (you) with 2 reputation points.

Comment: @Myles : Marking an answer as accepted will also indicate to other users having the same problem that this solution worked for you.

Comment: Also lets us use it as a dupe landing pad when someone posts a similar question. And they will.